# How can I disable moving / animated pictures in documentation?

Tags: macos, firefox, images, visual-studio-code, documentation

I would like to learn Visual Studio Code, but I cannot get past its "modern" and "engaging" [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs). The very first screen you get when I browse to this URL has a moving picture, and it only gets worse when I try to read some detailed section such as about the keyboard shortcuts. I am simply unable to absorb any information when stuff moves in front of me; I learn by reading only. So how can I disable these elements in my browser? I wish I could be more specific about the technology with which it is done , but I'm not a Web programmer (no Javascript).

I use Firefox on a Mac, but I could be persuaded to use a different browser and maybe Linux for this task if that helps.

Comment: Download a book?

Comment: @JohnRennie : can you suggest one? (with a URL if possible)

Comment: I would search the Z-Library for "Visual Studio Code" and have a skim through the books there to see if you can find one you like.